# visualization clusters in R (using apcluster)

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, cluster-analysis

I need get visualization of my clusters, but by template.
i mean, here my data.

```
mydat<- read.csv("mydat.csv",sep=";", dec=",")
```

dput

```
  structure(list(x1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), x3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), x5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), x6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
        x7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), x8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
        0L)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", 
    "x8"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

i performed cluster analysis

```
library("apcluster")
apres1 <- apclusterK(negDistMat(r=2), df, K=25)
apres1
```

How can i visualize the result, that clusters were displayed like in this picture
[image]

edited for Ken.S
I tried do so

```
plot(apres1, mydat)
```

but the visualization is not suit me
[image]

i dont't want have  25 plots, i want have 1 plot, like if i perform classification

Comment: @KenS. i edited post where  decribed , what i have done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select 2 column that you wanted to plot.

```
library("apcluster")
for(i in 1:3)
{
x11()
m=i
n=i+1
mehul= iris[,c(m,n)]
apres1 <- apclusterK(negDistMat(r=3),mehul,K=3)
plot(apres1,mehul)
}
```

[image]

Comment: i must only two columns plot, x1,x2, then x3,x4, then x4,x1,?Is it possible to write a loop, so that all the columns were ploted alternately.., i.e. there will be a large number separate plot . Do you understand my idea? (1-3,1-5,2-5, 2-3)....

Comment: Ya got it, You can use x11() to plot every graph in new windows and create a loop for different plot

Comment: Can you edited your answer with this loop to show me, then i accept your answer

Comment: I'm happy to answer your question. please give me some more time.